# How to easily make a sequence of circular images resembling a pie charts in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make a set of images similar to this: http://petewilliamsagency.com/oldsite/css/examples/pie/slices.gif.  This won't actually be used for a pie chart, but instead a more unique method of displaying percents.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the angles like that in Photoshop (using CS4 if that matters).  The circles are of course simple enough, and I have no problem making all of the easy 45 degree angle slices, but the smaller ones (5, 10, 15, etc) are giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a circle. Repeat until circle is filled:

1. Draw a vertical line, in your fill color, from the center to the top of the circle.
2. Rotate 5 degrees.
3. Draw a vertical line, in your fill color, from the center to the top of the circle.
4. Fill the wedge.
5. Save as a new image.